# MongoDB: Finding client connected to the Mongodb database

Tags: mongodb

How to find a particular client connected to the mongodb databse. Is there any command to find it from Mongo shell. For example, If there is any web application connected to the database and if I want to check whether it is connected and to find its IP address, is there any way to find it? If so please let me know. When I run the below command, it displays only localhost. Other clients are not shown. Please help.

rs:PRIMARY> db.currentOp(true).inprog.forEach(function(d){if (d.client)printjson(d.client)})
"127.0.0.1:43424"
"127.0.0.1:58214"
"127.0.0.1:56887"

Answer (score 0):

```
db.serverStatus().connections
```

client connection details

```
db.currentOp(true)
```

shows the current operations deatils

```
db.currentOp(true).inprog.forEach(function(inPro){if(inPro.client && inPro.client!="0.0.0.0:0")print(inPro.client)})
```

i think this will solve your problem

Comment: Below is the output when I run the command 'rs:PRIMARY> db.currentOp(true).inprog.forEach(function(inPro){if(inPro.client && inPro.client!="0.0.0.0:0")print(inPro.client)})
127.0.0.1:51658
127.0.0.1:43424
127.0.0.1:56887
It is only showing the localhost. Its not displaying the application Ip address connected to it.

Comment: Can you please explain your application flow (front end-service layer-back end(mongodb)). I think your application will be communicating to a service and it will be communicating database , i think you are running service in local machine.the 127.0.0.1:Portno is connecting to database so it is showing in the result. if you want application ip you can code it in service layer. In that case this is not a issue related to mongodb, it will be related to your service